# ASPNETCORE_TEMP environment Variable for specific endpoint .NET CORE 5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Need to use different temp folders in different cases for Buffering during large file uploading process

[File upload scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0#file-upload-scenarios)

Is .NET 5 has some way to configure it dynamically?

Already have ASPNETCORE_TEMP environment Variable configured. But it is a global setting.
I need some setting that can be configured for each request.
Thx.

Comment: Any particular reason why do you need to do this?

Comment: @GuruStron some files will be saved directly on server folders and other on CDN storage

Comment: Then you should switch to streaming and handle that manually. Temp is temp for a reason

Comment: @GuruStron Thx for the answer. But it is not a valid answer for my question.

Comment: First of all it is not an answer)

Comment: @GuruStron do u have some 'second of all' ? :)

Comment: Since,it was based on the enviroment  Variable,have you tried with Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable() method  to modify the value of Variable?I couldn't try it myself now due to it requires  Admin's permission